# Increment int on button click c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to increment integer on every button click, I'm using viewstate to assign value to my int, but it doesn't work. here is my code samples

```
 public int par
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["par"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["par"] = 2;
        }
        return (int)ViewState["par"];
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["par"] = value;
    }
}
```

and button click event:

```
 protected void LoadMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.par = this.par + 1;
        loadNews(Convert.ToInt32(this.par));

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

problem is that on first click number is incremented by one, but on next clicks nothing happens..

Comment: "Doesnt work" is not enough information.

Comment: Nice, what is the question?

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled for your application?

Comment: weird...!? add details

Comment: Do something else in the button click that's not dependant on the view state, like just writing some literal text to the response.  My guess is you aren't properly creating the button or adding the event handler and as a result the entire click handler isn't running.

Comment: You convert int to int brilliant!   - Fists it was string, so I forgot to edit this line ..

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens? in first click you get 3 and the next one is 4 do you have newsWithId == 4 or you get completely different error.

Comment: In your codebehind, what is the value of this expression Page.EnableViewState ?

Comment: Page.EnableViewState = true; in first click i get value 3 and next clicks doesn't increment it's value. it is always 3

Comment: Then the only most probable explanation is, that the event isn't being triggered at all. Can you post code, where are you subscribing LoadMore_Click to Click even (either markup or codebehind).

Comment: Set breakpoint in `par` property and when you click button second or third time check `ViewState["par"] == null` always evaluates to true. This is another way you'll get 3 all the time.

Comment: that means either the View state is not enabled in page level or userControl level if you are in user control or you set the value on page load to null or 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number= 0;
protected void btnIncrement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number++;
    ViewState["number"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["number"]) + number;
    lblShow.Text = ViewState["number"].ToString();
}
```

I guess this will work.

Comment: How is this any different than the OPs code, other than that his code wraps the view state access in a property (which is better than what you're doing in my opinion)?

Comment: For that matter a class level field is a strange way to write `+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int number = 0;
public int par
{
    get
    {
        return number;
    }
    set
    {
        number = value;
    }
}

protected void LoadMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number++;
    lblShow.Text = par.ToString();

    try
    {
        loadNews(par);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
        lblShow.Text += ex.Message; 
    }
}
```

Comment: this always returns 1 not an increment.

Comment: I thought that the only thing that should increment was the `Click` event?

Comment: @JPHellemons This question is asked in the context of Asp.Net. Local class fields will *not* persist across click events.